# Wordpress Slider

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, slider, carousel

Has anyone seen a wordpress plugin slider that will show partially the next and previous image before it slides in? OR does anyone know of one that may be easily customized to show that effect? any demos, guidance or links will be extremely helpful!
Thanks very much in advance!

- Michael

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress jQuery Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-slider/) worked well for me.

Then all you need is to add code like this and customise it within wordpress:

```
<?php if(function_exists('jquery-slider')){ jquery-slider(); } ?>
```

To access what you've added. Where you want to put this is up to you; within the main, footer, or your blog posts.